# Determine the matrix that rotates $R^3$ vectors around a given line.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, rotations

Determine the matrix A that rotates $R^3$ vectors the angle $\theta $ around the line $\begin{cases}x=t\\y=-t\\z=0\end{cases}$

My solution:

$\hat{v}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix}1\\-1\\0\end{pmatrix}$

A vector $\vec{u}$ is projected on the line by $\vec{u_p}=(\vec{u}\cdot\hat{v})\hat{v}$

The vector from the projection to $\vec{u}$ is $\vec{u}-\vec{u_p}=\vec{u}-(\vec{u}\cdot\hat{v})\hat{v}=\vec{w}$

$\vec{w}$ is perpendicular to the line and can now be seen as the x-axis of a circle with its origin at the point of vector $\hat{v}$.

$\vec{w_n}=\hat{v}\times\vec{w}$ can be seen as the circles y-axis.

Therefore $\vec{w'}$, which is $\vec{w}$ rotated $\theta$ degrees on the circle, can be expressed: $\vec{w'}=\cos{\theta}\vec{w}+\sin{\theta}\vec{w_n}$

And finally $\vec{u'}=\vec{u_p}+\vec{w'}$

Through replacing $\vec{u}$ with $\hat{e_x},\hat{e_y},\hat{e_z}$ I calculated the matrix to be:

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\cos{\theta}&-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\cos{\theta}&-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sin{\theta}
\\-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\cos{\theta}&\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\cos{\theta}&-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sin{\theta}
\\\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\sin{\theta}&\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sin{\theta}&\cos{\theta}
\end{pmatrix}$$

Is there a simpler method to do this?

Comment: It is enough to find an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$ containing the unit vector of this line and then do the rotation in the plane spanned by the other two vectors. If you insist on writing everything in the standard basis, then all you have to do is to multiply by a suitable change of basis matrix.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly; do rotation around one axis, and then if needed rotate that axis in the plane that has both axis and line in it..

Comment: Yes. That is the general idea. Although you have to choose the axis of rotation wisely.

Comment: @AniruddhaDeshmukh Thank you.